# how to optimize the sql which contains same "in" sentence?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select *
from t_link a
WHERE a.STAR_CITY_ID in (select cityId from `t_map_city` t
                         WHERE t.PROVINCEID = 350) and
      a.END_CITY_ID in (select cityId from `t_map_city` t
                        WHERE t.PROVINCEID = 350);
```

This is my sql. How can I optimize it to improve the efficiency?

```
select * from `t_ne$link` a 
JOIN (select cityId from `t_map_city` t WHERE t.PROVINCEID=350) tb1 
  on (a.END_CITY_ID in (tb1.cityId) and a.STAR_CITY_ID in (tb1.cityId))；
```

I have changed it to this, but it does not work.

Comment: Why? Is it slow? The engine should cache the subquery result. So it is executed only once.

Comment: The old sql is too slow . After i changed it ,it even can not query the right result .

Comment: It can be slow for many reason. Most common reason: missing index.

Comment: The old sql ,this part "(select cityId from `t_map_city` t
                         WHERE t.PROVINCEID = 350)" is execluted twice times .

Comment: "is execluted twice" - How do you know?

Comment: because a.STAR_CITY  and a.END_CITY_ID  have the same condition

Comment: You query is almost fine (you can turn the superfluous nested query into a simple join). If you still have performance issues - start with inspecting the execution plan and checking indexes.

Comment: Seems you didn't read, what I wrote about cache in my first comment. However.. first check your indexes `SHOW CREATE <table_name>` should help. Also check `EXPLAIN <your_query>`. Post the results in your question. Until then - we don't know enough to help you.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion.

Comment: You new query imply that `a.STAR_CITY_ID = a.END_CITY_ID`. I suspect it is not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using explicit joins:

```
select l.*
from t_link l join
     t_map_city mcs
     on l.start_city_id = mcs.cityId and
        mcs.provinceid = 350 join
     t_map_city mce
     on l.start_city_id = mce.cityId and
        mce.provinceid = 350;
```

For performance, you probably want an index on `t_map_city(cityId, provinceId)`.

Comment: Thanks for you help.It words fine.

Answer (score 1):

Well, using `EXISTS` also might help:

```
select *
from t_link a
WHERE exists(select 1 from `t_map_city`
             where cityId = a.start_city_id and provinceId = 350)
and exists(select 1 from `t_map_city`
             where cityId = a.end_city_id and provinceId = 350)
```

Comment: Thanks for you help to provide me with another way to solve the problem!

Comment: @lanxu You should accept (green check mark left to the answer) answer that helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `IN` clauses are just perfect for the job. (One could do the same with `EXISTS`, but this should result in the same execution plan of course.)

Provide the following index to get the cities for a province quickly:

```
create idx_province_city on t_map_city (provinceid, city_id);
```

If this is still too slow, then we must resort to a trick. I consider joining instead of the straight-forward `IN` or `EXISTS` clauses such a trick. (And a sad trick at that, because the DBMS should easily see that the two queries do the same thing and come up with the same execution plan hence).

Another trick would be to look up tuples:

```
create index idx_city_tuple on t_link (star_city_id, end_city_id);

select *
from t_link a
where (star_city_id, end_city_id) in
(
  select a.cityId, b.cityId
  from       (select cityId from t_map_city where provinceid = 350) a
  cross join (select cityId from t_map_city where provinceid = 350) b
);
```

I don't like this approach myself, but would apply it still, if I were in desperate need to boost my query. (And then it's still to see whether this is really faster.)